# using \leftmark gives me the section label rather than the section name

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, footnotes, fancyhdr, titlesec

I write my lectures in separate documents and when I include them in the main document I use `\leftmark` in the header to display the section.

I tried something new, adding a footnote to the section using
`\section[title]{<lecture name>\footnote{}}` for a url to the lecture slides, In case I want to quickly access them while reading my notes.

Now however `\leftmark` simply just says 'title' rather than the actual lecture name. Is there any way to get around this problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you provide a small compilable example document that demonstrates this problem? That would make it much easier to see where the issue is and to try out possible solutions that will actually apply in your situation.

Comment: Do you mean that you actually have `\section[title}{...}` in your file?  If that is the case, replace "title" by the lecture name without the footnote.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks that worked